# 2SLS with time series in R (with dynlm package?)

Tags: r, time-series

I want to do the two-stage least squares estimation with time series. I know I can do it manually, but the standard errors then are not right.

I accidentally saw in the description of the `dynlm` package that it includes 2SLS estimation. However, I don't seem to understand how to do it. All that we are given in the instructions is:

> To specify a set of instruments, formulas of type `y ~ x1 + x2 | z1 + z2` can be used where z1 and z2 represent the instruments.

How do I specify which variable (`x1` or `x2`) is endogenous (and would be dependent variable in the first stage)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the right of `|` you want to specify all the instruments - including the exogenous variable already in the equation. Whatever is not on the right will be instrumented - assumed to be endogenous. So, if `x1` is exogenous, `x2` is endogenous, and you have one extra instrument `z1`, then you want

```
y ~ x1 + x2 | z1 + x1
```

To see that this is right, try including just `z1` on the right: then one coefficient will be not identified.